# scope of an array retrieved from HTTP Get request in angularcli

Tags: angular, http-get

Why am I not able to print the array address1 outside the get request?
I got stuck with this.can someone help me out with this?

I have also tried using XMLHttpRequest() ,even it shows the same problem.

```
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  private elements = [];
  searchURL = "http://.......";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() : void {
  var address1 = [];
  var i;
  this.httpClient.get(this.searchURL).subscribe((res : any[]) =>{
  this.elements = res;
  for(i=0;i<this.elements.data.length;i++){
  address1.push(this.elements.data[i].location);
  //console.log(address1[i]);//prints here 
  }
 });

 //Not printing here 
   for(i=0;i<address1.length;i++){
   console.log(address1[i]);
   console.log('in');
   }

 }

}
```

Comment: Make `var address1` variable as `public variable1`

Comment: Basics of async coding. Your response isn't available when the second code bite is reached.

Comment: so, what do i need to do to access the data retrieved from get request .or how to make the second bite execute after the get request?

Answer (score 1):

`this.httpClient.get` is of type observable so it is called asynchronously. `console.log(address1[i]);` is outside of it, so this line gets executed first. Therefore you are not getting the result

Answer (score 0):

You can access `address1[]` outside the request's subscription - it's declared in `ngOnInit` and lives within its closure - but obviously you won't have any content until after the request has the chance to be resolved. Your "Not printing here" loop gets executed before the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

Hello As your code is executing before response of Http so do the following to print data

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

    private elements = [];
    searchURL = "http://.......";
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    public address:any = []
    ngOnInit() : void {
        var address1 = [];

        this.httpClient.get(this.searchURL).subscribe((res : any[]) =>{
            this.elements = res;
            for(let i=0;i<this.elements.data.length;i++){
                address1.push(this.elements.data[i].location);
                (this.address).push(this.elements.data[i].location);
                //console.log(address1[i]);//prints here 
            }

            for(let j=0;j<address1.length;j++){
               console.log(address1[j]);
               console.log('in');
           }
            console.log("this.address::",this.address);
        });

     }

}
```

if you want to use it in html file then use **address** key

Answer (score 0):

This is due to asynchronous behavior of http.get so if you want to use address1[] use it after you get response not outside.